# Optimize a query with a three-way JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, join, explain

*I have the following query what is the suggests to make it better and how to avoid null values.*

```
SELECT stream.id AS status_id, 
       members.username, 
       members.membership_type, 
       members.first_name, 
       members.last_name, 
       stream.member_id, 
       stream.url_preview,
       stream.media,
       stream.images,  
       stream.poll_id, 
       stream.status_type, 
       stream.created_at, 
       stream.activity_text, 
       stream.original_id, 
       stream.shared_from 
FROM stream, follow, members 
WHERE follow.follower_id = 239 
AND stream.member_id = members.id
AND (stream.member_id=follow.follower_id OR stream.member_id=follow.member_id) 
AND stream.type = 2 
AND stream.status_type NOT IN (4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11) 
GROUP BY stream.id 
ORDER BY stream.id DESC 
LIMIT ' . $offset . ', 10;
```

---

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys         | key         | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stream  | index  | member_id             | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL                    |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | members | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY     | 4       | portal.stream.member_id |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | follow  | ref    | follower_id,member_id | follower_id | 4       | const                   |   14 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+-----------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Where are you learning to write table joins in this old style (< 1992)?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "how to avoid null values."

Comment: I want to avoid null which in explain output in column of ref.

Comment: About the old style tell me what is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its quite obvious that you are  using old style of joining, still if you need to avoid `NULL` value to show on data then you can use  [IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function for avoiding NULL.

Example :-

```
select ifnull(members.username,'this is null part') as username from table_name;
```

This query will print the null part ,if the username is null either it will print the username only.

You can apply to your all column when you are fetching the column data in your query.

Hope it will help you.